# Try Catch Not Working on BadImageFormatException

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dllimport

I have a MVC app that is loading a external DLL and when in production I get no error at all.  Firefox just says the connection was reset.  So I put some try/catch in the code but they still do not work, I still get the connection reset message.

I know the error is a BadImageFormatException but why don't I see anything in the browser?

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        [DllImport("CDCrypt.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public static extern String Encrypt([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String aName);



        [DllImport("CDCrypt.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public static extern String Decrypt([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String aName);


        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            try
            {
                ViewBag.EncryptString = Encrypt("test");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ViewBag.EncryptString = "Stack Trace\r\n:" + "\r\nException: " + e.Message;
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(500);
            }
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Up()
        {
            ViewBag.Up = "You can see me";
            return View();
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There seem to be some exceptions which are marked as unrecoverable and so cannot be caught.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546580/why-is-it-not-possible-to-catch-missingmethodexception) (well [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546580/why-is-it-not-possible-to-catch-missingmethodexception/3546609#3546609) really) has a list of them, but I don't know how exhaustive this is.

[This article](http://www.netfxharmonics.com/2006/10/uncatchable-exception) has some more information about uncatchable exceptions, and how they can be caught if you throw them but not if the runtime throws them.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738276/can-an-async-i-o-throw-an-uncatchable-exception/787999#787999) says that doing a `catch` rather than a `catch(Exception ex)` will allow COM exceptions to be caught as well.  Don't know if this will help (I doubt it) but is interesting, and might.

Comment: I've tried throwing a new expception in the try catch block and they are all caught though

Comment: see my edit - it seems they can be caught if you throw them, but not if the runtime does...

Comment: yeah I didn't hold out too much hope for that.

Comment: Next step is to try and fix it and be able to actually load the dll http://stackoverflow.com/q/6254824/84539

Answer (score 3):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.badimageformatexception.aspx

> The exception that is thrown when the
>   file image of a dynamic link library
>   (DLL) or an executable program is
>   invalid.

I will put this crudely - your program itself is not able to run, so there is no point in having the Try-Catch.

> COM methods report errors by returning
>   HRESULTs; .NET methods report them by
>   throwing exceptions. The runtime
>   handles the transition between the
>   two.

Have a look here for some not so crude explanation on how to map HRESULTs and Exceptions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ztbc5s1.aspx

Comment: Thank you, that'll explain it