# ASP.Net MVC DllImport BadImageFormatException 32bit/64bit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

I have the below code which is throwing a `BadImageFormatException`.  The DLL it's loading is 32bit.  The web server is running Windows 64bit but the application pool is set to Enable 32 bit.  Is there any way I can get this to work?

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [DllImport("CDCrypt.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public static extern String Encrypt 
        ([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String aName);

    [DllImport("CDCrypt.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public static extern String Decrypt
        ([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String aName);

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        try
        {
            ViewBag.EncryptString = Encrypt("test");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ViewBag.EncryptString =
                "Stack Trace\r\n:" + "\r\nException: " + e.Message;
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(500);
        }
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Up()
    {
        ViewBag.Up = "You can see me";
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: are you compiling it as 32-bit or any-cpu?

Comment: I've tried both and neither are able to load the dll

Comment: What is CDCrypt.dll?  You'll have to set your WP to use the same "bitness" as any unmanaged dlls.  If you have more than one, they must all match.

Answer (score 1):

Both the library and the consumer have to be the same. So determine what your lib you are calling is and ensure you are compiling for that type. Now - IIS itself (at least v 6) can only run one mode OR the other for *everything* so it either needs to be set for 64 or 32 bit across the board . See this
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/894435

in conjunction with:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfx64bit/thread/35b09f74-1d8e-4676-90e3-c73a439bf632/

Comment: Its using iis 7 and i tried compiling the site against x86 but no luck

Comment: hmm.. iis 7 then I think only requires the worker process to be 32 bit - put some code in to ensure you are 32 bit as a double check - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953377/how-to-know-a-process-is-32-bit-or-64-bit-programmatically

Comment: I added the code in that link, compiled against x86 ran the web page and it says its 32bit which would indicate all is ok so why the exception http://encrypt.tbmaster.co.uk/home/up shows the output.  http://encrypt.tbmaster.co.uk/home/index is the problem

Comment: I recompiled against x64 and now get a YSOD saying it cant find the main web app dll which would indicate it is running in 32bit maybe

Comment: Ive installed Windows 2008 and can replicate the problem and can see by turning Enable32bit mode on and off that its working. I just dont know how to fix this issue